# codeigniter session data gets lost

Tags: codeigniter, session, controller, localhost

i already posted this question but still wasnt able to resolve this issue.
seems that everyone has this problem with codeigniter .
When i set my session in a controller it works perfectly and i can display it.
WHen i move to another controller, the (CUSTOM) session data is completely lost.
i tried changing my cookie_domain in config.php. Since i am on localhost i tried `localhost` with without `/` and `localhost/codeigniter` and `sodeigniter` all did not work. i am lost
btw, i read somewhere that this happens when 2 ajax requests happen at the same time. could that be the problem? 
Or maybe tell me how you resolved the problem if you had same issues

screw this, i am swithing to php native sessions. if anyone wants to do that,
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PHPSession

Comment: are you loading the session library on all page requests? $this->load->library('Session');

Comment: where do you try to retrieve the custom session data?

Comment: @Yan in another controller. once login is successfull i get rid of anything inside `body` and load view from controller `home`. so i try to get my session data there but no luck

Comment: please try to remove the second ajax call. Is the data saved successfully into the session?

Comment: @Yan even if i do that, session is not even accessible between functions of the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check and double-check your code or any external libraries you are using for a stray sess_destroy().  I ran into a similar problem where I was storing an id in the session for reference but if the user then logs in the SimpleLogin library I was using for logins just destroys the entire session including data I did not want to lose.

This is what I get for not writing my own code.